# Google indexing Cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, google-index, aws-lambda-edge

I have a static site through Cloudfront with an S3 origin & custom domain via Route 53. All works well, except that Google has also indexed the Cloudfront distribution url (d123etc.cloudfront.net) as well as my custom domain, leading to duplicate content issues.

I've tried canonical urls, but the distribution remains indexed. It has been suggested to serve up a different robots.txt depending on what domain is being used, which sounds fine, but there is no .htaccess or web server, leaving it to a Lambda Edge function to try and send the different robots.txt.

The problem is that I can't find how in the function to determine if a request is coming from my custom domain or from the direct distribution url. I've tried white-listing the Origin, but it is not sent through when using an S3 origin. I've also tried white-listing the Referer header, but no referrer is sent through when accessing the robots.txt file as it's a direct request.

For the time-being, I'm adding a meta noindex client-side using js on page load (which I realise is too late), and also redirecting client-side to my actual domain in case someone follows the google indexed cloudfront.net domain.

Does anyone know how to detect in Lambda Edge which domain is being used to make the request? Or some other way of blocking Google from indexing the Cloudfront url, just leaving it to index the custom domain.

Comment: did you check the Host header in the request? 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html

Answer (score 0):

So I think the way to do this would be to set up a redirect on your hosted webserver. If you check the 'host' in the request header and check for cloudfront.com, send a 301 response code along with your custom domain name.

S3 has a UI way to do this:

https://medium.com/tensult/how-to-do-site-redirection-using-aws-522a4002c645

It seems you'll need a second bucket behind the same cloudfront url but without the custom domain. Then you can set it to redirect all requests to your custom domain.

The browser or bots would then stop trying cloudfront.com because it doesn't return anything, they would automatically (without the user really noticing) to my domain.xyz and all the links would link to your own domain.

Comment: Thanks. I already have the relevant CNAMEs & A-record aliases set, so Google does know about my custom domain. But that does not make the direct cloudfront domain inaccessible, and there doesn't seem to be a way to remove it from the Google index once it's in there unless I can get a blocking robots.txt served up on the cloudfront domain, while having a normal robots.txt served on my custom domain,

Comment: Hm, good point. Do you have control over the DNS zone for your cloudfront domain?

Comment: No if I understand the question correctly. I wouldn't think so. cloudfront.net is owned by amazon.

Comment: cloudfront.com is but they assigned you a unique subdomain, so they may allow you to set records for that subdomain. I'll look into it.

Comment: As hopefully explained in the question, there is no web server. No apache, no .htaccess, no Express. Just a static site on an S3 bucket served through a cloudfront distribution. And Lambda Edge functions are normally used to do this kind of processing. But I can't tell what domain the request is coming form. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently, albeit I have a web server instead of S3. It seems to be a very rare quirk of a Google robot.

The only possible way it might have learned about the CloudFront URL is via the DNS query. I had a CNAME DNS record pointing to the distribution, so it looked like this

```
> nslookup site.com
Non-authoritative answer:
site.com  canonical name = dfsdfsdfsdf.cloudfront.net.
Name:   dfsdfsdfsdf.cloudfront.net
Address: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

So I switched to an ALIAS A record, and now it's like this:

```
> nslookup site.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   site.com
Address: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I'm not sure this is 100% bulletproof, but this was the only lead I had.